# Is Symfony2 Preview Release Ready For Production?

Tags: symfony1, php, symfony

I have used Symfony 1.4 since it's release, but I now have the option to upgrade to Symfony2 for my next project. Does anyone have any experience? Is anybody currently building a production app on Symfony2 or have in the past few months?

EDIT: yes, Symfony2 website has been put up with a clear message saying the framework will be released tomorrow! There is no 'beta talk' but it does clearly state on the installation page that you should use 1.4 for new projects.

EDIT: somebody voted to close because this question is apparently 'too localized'. Is that not what tags are for?!

Comment: I went to copy and paste the standard 'Symfony 2 is not ready for production use blah blah blah' that used to be on the symfony reloaded website when I saw.... whoa, brand new shiny website and it says symfony 2 standard edition will be available tomorrow!? Much coolness.

Comment: The 'will be available tomorrow' text has been there for at least 3 days, possibly more. Also, it only means the availability of an RC build, final is planner for the end of March.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Symfony2 should be released in March and I'm guessing it should be in the next few days. The *Preview Release* always had a note next to it that it is *not* ready for production. I cannot tell how much is that really true and how much is that just the usual "beta talk".

If you've noticed, they changed the [symfony2 page](http://www.symfony-reloaded.org/) that now doesn't go to the preview page but to the symfony.com instead. Also some new tutorial(s) came up. And the download page shows a promising "*Will be available tomorrow*" message!

I tried out playing around with the symfony2 sandbox but before porting my application to it, I've decided to wait for the release version. If your project is not pressing, I'd suggest the same. Should be around the corner.

Just my two cents ;)

---

**EDIT**: Btw, if you look [in the blog](http://symfony.com/blog/a-week-of-symfony-217-21-27-february-2011), you can see that

> The public API of Symfony2 will be
>   frozen in just a few days. Therefore,
>   this week developers committed some of
>   the last big impact changes to the
>   code repository: the Response was
>   removed from DIC, CompatAssetsBundle
>   was removed in favor of AsseticBundle,
>   and the boostrap files were also
>   removed.

This can only mean a stable version out soon!

Comment: I can only hope that after sooo long developement, it's going to be good and stable from the first version on.

Comment: I hope so too! Because I think I'm going to take the dive :) you only live once! hehe

Comment: @Zenph, the symfony2 sandbox was quite a good start for a nice cooling dive! Unfortunately, I can't find a link to it on the new site so hopefully it's coming back.

Comment: git://github.com/symfony/symfony-sandbox.git :)

Comment: @Zenph, see? You don't need me! :D

Comment: "Tomorrow" According to the (urban)dictionary: A lot of people say that it is the day after today and that tomorrow will be here at midnight, but if you actually wait until midnight it is today again.  Often used by people to put off work as the new required deadline will never arrive.

Comment: As Jonas has foretold, [Symfony2 is delayed](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony2-final-version-we-are-not-there-yet).

Answer (score 2):

I would say yes, as long as you're aware that it's a preview release and take the necessary precaution i.e. keeping an eye on the error logs.

There are alot of sites using symfony2 in production including the VPS control panel at ServerGrove and OpenSky (developed by the creator and main contributor to doctrine orm and odm projects).

The Release Candidate comes this month sometime, which signifies the API becoming stable! Hooray!

[This link](http://symfony.com/blog/stabilizing-symfony2) from the Symfony2 blog outlines the road map for the Symfony2 release.

There's also the [Symfony2 Bundles](http://symfony2bundles.org/) site which is a collection of bundles that already exist for Symfony2

Answer (score 1):

They said it will be available soon.

But you already can download it from [github](http://github.com/symfony/symfony) and start learning it and migrating to it. I've been doing that since December last year and the only problem was changes in API. But now it must be more stable and it's safe to migrate to it.

The 'is not ready for production' note meant no support and no guarantees that everything works and tomorrow something won't change. And if it changes, it was your problem to find out what and how.

Answer (score 1):

While the original plan was to release a stable release candidate last week around the Symfony Live conference in Paris, it was announced there that it would be delayed for what I guess should be at least a couple of more weeks, which I agree is a good thing.

That means that the API is not stable yet and might change, and that those changes might break BC. The standard package which is now available for download on the new website is a PR like the previous releases were.